# Value of x for which the function $f(x)= (x-a1)^2 + (x-a2)^2 + (x-a3)^2 + ..... (x-an)^2$ takes on the minimum value. a1,a2....an are n real numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Given  $a1_,a_2....a_n$ are n real numbers, What is the value of x for which the function $f(x)= (x-a_1)^2 + (x-a_2)^2 + (x-a_3)^2 + ..... (x-a_n)^2$ takes on the minimum value.  ?

I can solve it using differentiation , but is there any way without involving calculus, and using algebra only ?

like I was thinking of using the fact that $(x-a_1)^2$ would be minimum at $x=a_1$, similarly $(x-a_2)^2$ would be minimum at $x=a_2$, so this would give $x=a_1=a_2=a_3....=a_n$ ,  but the answer that has been provided is $1/n * (a_1+a_2+....+a_n)$ any help as to how can I tackle this problem

Comment: (The not-accepted answer there is purely algebraic. The answer here implicitly uses calculus.)

Comment: @ParclyTaxel: Actually, the questions are **different**. This OP is actually asking not what the title says. The actual question is, why the values at $a_i$ are not the minimum. You have sufficient privileges and you may want to change the title to *"Why $a_i$ are not \(local\) minimums?"* or similar and reopen the question. My answer addresses exactly this question. And I am trying to answer it not via formulas, but rather I'm trying to make it understandable intuitively.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider a simple example:

$f(x)=(x-3)^2 + (x-5)^2$

$f(3)=(3-3)^2 + (3-5)^2 = 4$

$f(5)=(5-3)^2 + (5-5)^2 = 4$

Whereas

$f(4)=(4-3)^2 + (4-5)^2 = 2$

Means, neither $x=3$ nor $x=5$ is a minimum.

Let's move by a small step 0.1 to the right from $x = 3$:

- The part $(x-3)^2$ changes by $0.01$, i.e. it is *ascending*
- The part $(x-5)^2$ changes by $-0.39$, i.e. it is *descending*
- Thus the sum $f(x)$ changes by $0.01-0.39=-0.38$, i.e. it is *descending*

One part is ascending not as much as the other one is descending. That's why the sum of the both is *descending*. Since the function is *descending* to the right from $x=3$, the $x=3$ is not a minimum.

In case of multiple parts $(x-a_i)$ the logic is the same.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I am not able to figure out how did you calculate those ascending and descending parts 0.6 for $(x-3)^2$ and 1.0 for  $(x-5)^2$

Comment: @Fin27: Good point. I have corrected it.

Comment: cool !... Can you come up with an intuitive reasoning here as well as to why at x= mean of $a_1$,$a_2$....$a_n$ would give us minimum value of the function

Comment: @Fin27: If you find it helpful, you may want to vote it up. To the explanation: Around the point $x=3$ the impact of $(x-3)^2$ is essentially less than the impact of $(x-5)^2$. In the general case, the impact of the part with "local zero" around $a_i$ is essentially less than the impact of other parts. That's why the value of the function can be less than the value at $a_i$. That's why $a_i$ is not necessarily a minimum.